# Grails: Children of Children

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a question about GORM and "multiple" hasmany relationships, and I didn't find an answer in my previous searches.

Let's say we have three domains:

```
class A {
...
static hasMany = [Bs: B]
}
```

and

```
class B {
...
static belongsTo = A
static hasMany = [Cs: C]
}
```

and

```
class C {
static belongsTo = B
String name
dateCreated date
}
```

I want to know if it is possible to get a list of objects of the class C, sorted by dateCreated, using an object of the class A (something like C.findAll(...., a: a.id) ) or if I have to use a more complex query ?

Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a little more difficult because you aren't storing a back reference to the parent objects

Something like this - I didn't test it myself

```
A.executeQuery("select distinct c from A a join a.bs as b join b.cs as c where a = :a", [a: a])
```

Comment: Thanks James for your solution. After some tests, I didn't use your query but I added a back reference in my domain class (more simple in my opinion).

Answer (score 0):

If B has:
static belongsTo = [a:A]

then you can do:

```
C.withCriteria {
  a{
    eq('id', <a's id here>)
  }
  order('dateCreated', 'desc')
}
```